# Flask API works as expected when requested from ThunderClient, but refresh the navigator in some cases

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I have created a [Flask API](https://github.com/myke-oliveira/miniproyect-9/blob/main/server/main.py) to consume the OpenAI service to transcript a number in an audio file to the number written, and that works fine when requested from Thunder Client (integrated to the Visual Studio Code). However, when I tested the same cases from a [Front-End Web Application](https://github.com/myke-oliveira/miniproyect-9/blob/main/server/main.py), I got the web browser refreshed in some of the cases. I will show you the front-end code below.

```js
const file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file)

const URL = "http://localhost:5000"

try {
  const response = await fetch(URL, {
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: formData,
    method: "POST"
  })

  const data = await response.json()

  const html = data.error
    ? `<p class="fs-1"><strong>Error:</strong> ${data.error}</p>`
    : `<p class="fs-1"><strong>Result:</strong> ${data.text}</p>`

  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = html
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

When I was debugging this code I got the browser refreshed when the `fetch` is reached! The API Code is shown bellow.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'})

    file = request.files['file']

    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'error': 'No selected file'})

    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Format not valid.'})

    filename = file.filename
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    transcripted_number = transcript_number(filename)
    return jsonify(transcripted_number)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return any(map(lambda extention: filename.endswith(extention), ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS))


def transcript_number(filename):
    filepath = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as audiofile:
        transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audiofile)
    data = json.loads(str(transcript))
    print(data)
    text = data['text']
    
    try:
        float(text)
        return data
    except ValueError:
        print('erro')
        return { 'error': 'Number not found!' }
```

The pattern that I notice is that the error cases `Not file part`, `Not selected file`, and `Format not valid` work ok. However I never reached the success case and the `Number not found!` error.

I tried to change the fetch method for `XMLHttpRequest` and tried to change timeout option, without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this web navigator behavior only occurs when I am using LiveServer vscode extension. When I access as local file, everything is like I expected.